# Hibernate: need update parent entity without pulling all its child-cascade

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, data-persistence

I faced the problem when I need to partially udate data in BD.

**What I have:**
I have three linked entities:

**Profile** --*(1-m)*--> **Person** --*(1-1)*--> **Address**

Where Person -> Address is lazy relationship. It was achieved via optional=false option (that allow hibernate to use proxy).

**What the problem:**

*I need to **update Profile** in such way, that I **needn't pull all Addresses** that linked with this profile.*

When I update Profile (*don't work*):

```
profile.setPersons(persons);
session.saveOrUpdate(profile);
```

*throws*: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not null property references a null or transient value

It happens because Person->Address relationship has optional=false option

*I need to do:*

```
//for each person
Address address = requestAddressFromDB();
person.setAddress(address);
persons.add(person)
//and only then
profile.setPersons(persons);
session.saveOrUpdate(profile);
profile.setPerson(person)
```

But I don't want to pull all address each time I update Profile name.

**What is the question:**

How can I avoid obligatory Person->(not null)Address constraint to save my profile without pulling all addresses?

**ADDITION**:

```
@Entity
public class Person{

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_sequence", sequenceName = "sq_person")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_sequence")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long personID;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="person", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Address address;
  //.. getters, setters
}

@Entity
public class Address {

  @Id
  @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
  @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="person"))
  private long personID;

  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  @OneToOne
  private FileInfo person;
}
```

Comment: Post the entity and mapping between Person and Address

Comment: in addition section of my question

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `cascade` element on the `@OneToOne` annotation so that the `PERSIST` operation is not cascaded.  This may require you to manually persist updates to `Address` in certain areas of your code.  If the cascade is not really used however no change is needed.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="person", cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Adress address;  //Do you know that Address is missing a 'd'?
```

Comment: It doesn't help. But why it is SpringFrameworkViolationException but not a Hibernate one?

Comment: Short answer spring wraps a bunch of hibernate exceptions.

Comment: Sorry. Cause: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not null property references a null or transient value. It still doesn't work.